# Append second field of second line to first line from file

Tags: text-processing, awk

how to generate the following file ( example in ) to the file as described in example out ,

each last word in state line  ( example in ) , should be added to the last line of the previos line

example in

```
HDFS  worker01.gtdns.com
state  STARTED
HDFS  worker02.gtdns.com
state  STOP
HDFS  worker03.gtdns.com
state  STARTED
HDFS  worker05.gtdns.com
state  STARTED
HDFS  worker06.gtdns.com
state  STARTED
HDFS  worker07.gtdns.com
state  STARTED
HDFS  worker08.gtdns.com
state  STARTED
HDFS  worker09.gtdns.com
state  STOP
```

example out ( expected results )

```
HDFS  worker01.gtdns.com STARTED
HDFS  worker02.gtdns.com STOP
HDFS  worker03.gtdns.com STARTED
HDFS  worker05.gtdns.com STARTED
HDFS  worker06.gtdns.com STARTED
HDFS  worker07.gtdns.com STARTED
HDFS  worker08.gtdns.com STARTED
HDFS  worker09.gtdns.com STOP
```

Comment: `bash` is not a text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '$1 == "HDFS" { printf( "%s ", $0 ) }; $1=="state" { print $2 }' /path/to/input
```

The `awk` script is fairly self-explanatory:  On lines where the first field is `HDFS`, append a space to the line and print it as-is with no trailing newline.  On lines where the first field is `state`, print the second field *with* the (implied) trailing newline.

Comment: What's the reason for removing the `sed` and `perl` tags ? They're just as valid as `awk` here...

Comment: I thought I only removed the `sed` tag, but may have misdoubleclicked and caught `perl`'s tag inadvertently.  Feel free to re-add.

Comment: I don't want to re-add anything. As I said I'd like to know what's wrong with using e.g. the `sed` tag here...

Comment: Using `sed` to parse multi-line input is generally more complicated and prone to error than it's worth in my opinion, and given the nature of the OP, probably not the right hammer for this particular nail.

Comment: That's your opinion - a very subjective one at that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are always one state after the HDFS, This solve the issue:

```
awk '$1=="HDFS"{l=$0;next};$1=="state"{print(l,$2);l=""}' file
```

`$1=="HDFS"{ … }` For lines the field 1 is `HDFS` do `…`.
`l=$0;next` Store line in var `l` (elle, line) move to next line.
`$1=="state"{ … }` for lines that field 1 is `state` do …
`{print(l,$2)}` print the line stored in var `l` (elle) and field 2.
`{l=""}` Avoid printing stale (old) values of `l`.

Comment: golfing based on the `condition{action}` awk default synthax: `awk '$1=="HDFS"{l=$0}$1=="state"{print(l,$2)}'`

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeVasiliou answer edited, description added.

Comment: Just for fun, this can be golfed more if one state come always after HDFS: `awk '$1=="state"{print l,$2}{l=$0}'`. Give it a try.

Comment: Good idea. @GeorgeVasiliou Probably not much aster, but I like this better: `awk '$1=="state"{print l,$2;next}{l=$0}'`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Besides, the answer as it stands now seems more robust.

Answer (score 0):

gnu awk golfing:

```
$ awk '1' RS='\n[ \t]*state ' ORS='' file
```

Testing:

```
$ awk '1' RS='\n[ \t]*state ' ORS='' file
HDFS  worker01.gtdns.com STARTED
HDFS  worker02.gtdns.com STOP
HDFS  worker03.gtdns.com STARTED
HDFS  worker05.gtdns.com STARTED
HDFS  worker06.gtdns.com STARTED
HDFS  worker07.gtdns.com STARTED
HDFS  worker08.gtdns.com STARTED
HDFS  worker09.gtdns.com STOP
```

`RS` is the Input record separator
`ORS` is the output record separator

Answer (score 0):

Short GNU **`AWK`** approach:

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+state' '{ printf "%s", $0 }' file
```

- `-v RS='[[:space:]]+state'` - treat `state` substring with leading whitespace(s) `[[:space:]]+` as input record separator `RS`

The output:

```
HDFS  worker01.gtdns.com  STARTED
HDFS  worker02.gtdns.com  STOP
HDFS  worker03.gtdns.com  STARTED
HDFS  worker05.gtdns.com  STARTED
HDFS  worker06.gtdns.com  STARTED
HDFS  worker07.gtdns.com  STARTED
HDFS  worker08.gtdns.com  STARTED
HDFS  worker09.gtdns.com  STOP
```

---

For a "2-lined" static format - you may also try the following **`SED`** approach:

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*HDFS/{ N; s/[[:space:]]*state // }' file
```

Comment: The awk option accepts lines that have anything other than HDFS. Probably it doesn't matter, but worth knowing.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`ex`, the POSIX-specified scriptable file editor](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html):

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/state/s/^ *state *//|-j' x | ex file.txt
```

The `s` command is a standard substitution.  The `-j` means "on the previous line (`-`), execute the join command (`j`)" which joins the subsequent line with a space separation.

Actually, because the `j`oin command ignores leading spaces on the line to be joined, and because `s` reuses the previous regex if no regex is supplied, the following command works just as will and gives the same result:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/state/s///|-j' x | ex file.txt
```

Note that this saves the changes to the file.  To view the changes without saving them, use the following instead:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/state/s///|-j' %p | ex file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the result by using below sed one liner

```
 sed "s/state//g" filename| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"
```

output

```
HDFS  worker01.gtdns.com   STARTED
HDFS  worker02.gtdns.com   STOP
HDFS  worker03.gtdns.com   STARTED
HDFS  worker05.gtdns.com   STARTED
HDFS  worker06.gtdns.com   STARTED
HDFS  worker07.gtdns.com   STARTED
HDFS  worker08.gtdns.com   STARTED
HDFS  worker09.gtdns.com   STOP
```